# How can selection of delimiter matches be disabled?

Tags: front-end

I often preemptively match delimiters. As a simple example, I'll type `Import[]`, then left arrow, then `"filename"`.

The problem is that when I type the `]` in `Import[]`, the `[` highlights in the normal selection color to signify that this pair of brackets matches. During this automatic highlighting, if I type something that involves the shift key (such as something starting with `"`), the `]` is deleted, leaving `Import["`. This behavior is as if the `]` was selected when the `"` was typed, but it was not.

To reiterate, the sequence of keys is (quickly typed!) `Import[]` then <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> but the behavior is as if the sequence were `Import[]` and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>.

It might be my imagination, but it seems to have gotten worse in *Mathematica* version 9.

Can I disable or shorten the automatic highlighting of matching delimiters? It appears to be the source of the phantom shift keystroke.

This is Mathematica version 9 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

---

Wolfram support suggested unchecking "Enable dynamic highlighting" and this does not fix the problem. I recorded the problem happening twice in a row here. It happens a bit faster than it is being displayed here.

[image]

I'd settle for just shortening the duration of this highlighting so I'd have to be Superman to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, but it requires some extremely quick typing!  I can't actually type `"` fast enough, but I can type other Shift combinations.  Did you report this as a bug?

Comment: You should add your operating system, because here on Linux, I cannot reproduce it. One possible quick fix is to to type `Import` and then `Alt`+`]` which creates `[]` and positions the cursor inside the brackets.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you for reproducing it. I contacted support today.

Comment: @halirutan, thanks for the suggestion. On the Mac this is `cmd`+`alt`+`]`, which is not nearly as easy. Maybe I'll change the shortcut to `alt`+`]` and use this as the workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter highlighting time is controlled by the option `DelimiterFlashTime`, which can be set for a cell or a notebook or the entire front end. You can lower the value (default 0.3 seconds) or disable it entirely with a value 0.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DelimiterFlashTime -> 0]
```

Change to `$FrontEndSession` if you want to change it across all notebooks for the current session or use `$FrontEnd` if you want to change it for the entire front end from here onwards.

Comment: ConstantArray["thank you",Infinity]

Comment: You're welcome :)